# AWS IoT rule to republish from one thingShadow to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have two node.js applications, one running in a RPi (`device1`) and another on an AWS EC2 instance (`device2`).

`device1` uses thingShadow class and **updates** on a regular basis a status to topic `$aws/things/device1/shadow/update`.

`device2` uses the device class and **subscribes** to topic `$aws/things/device2/shadow/update`.

I created an AWS IoT rule to republish from `$aws/things/device1/shadow/update` topic to `$aws/things/device2/shadow/update` topic:

```
SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/device1/shadow/update'
```

and

publishes to `$aws/things/device2/shadow/update`

When `device1` updates `$aws/things/device1/shadow/update` I can monitor the message using a software like MQTT.fx, however absolutely nothing is sent to `$aws/things/device2/shadow/update`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled the AWS IoT service's logs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html Often if the IoT message broker is experiencing issues processing a message that is the only place you can find any information about it. You might also want to monitor the `$aws/things/device2/shadow/update/rejected` topic to watch for updates that are being rejected.

Comment: Also, are you sure your query shouldn't be: `SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/device1/shadow/update/accepted'`? That way only accepted updates for device1 would be republished to device2. See the list of all the device shadow topics here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-mqtt.html

Comment: I had already tried the `/update/accepted` topic but the behavior was the same. I will enable the log and see what I can find (thanks for pointing that out. I had no idea where to find this log!)

Answer (score 0):

You may need double $$ for the topic you want republish

Comment: That's only for reserved topic